# problem with ubuntu 12.10 minimize animation

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, 12.10, minimize

I have a small problem with the new ubuntu 12.10 minimize animation.
I currently have a laptop and a desktop, both upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10.
The problem shows up only on the desktop.
When I minimize a window, instead of viewing the whole window fade and zoom out, the content disappear, and only the bezel complete the animation.

Here is a short screencast that shows the behavior:

http://youtu.be/9fwlimfs85A

Any ideas on where I can look for a solution?

Many thanks in advance.
Regards.

**update**

Looks like the open source driver works perfectly. The problem is that the performance is not so cool, and some games that push a little the graphic (like torchligt) do not even startup. Linus is right about nvidia...

Comment: you should add the details of your nvidia card as well as the driver version you are using.  Have you tried the experimental drivers available such as v304 (install from synaptic)

Comment: yes, none of the three nvidia works. The open source one works but it's so slow...

Comment: The same is happening to me with Nvidia drivers .

Comment: As i'm also affected by this behavior i filed a bug for it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1104637

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Install [compizconfig-settings-manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager).
2. Run CompizConfig and click on **Animation**.
3. Go to the "Minimize animation" tab.

For me, the minimize effect is `zoom` and duration is `220` and of course the `enable animation` option is checked, on the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks! it's already set up like that...I think that the problem is related to the nvidia drivers, not a misconfiguration.

Comment: Try and disable the proprietary driver and use the default one and see if the problem is with that also...

Just to get an idea about the source of the error being the driver or configuration...

Comment: if you see the main question, after **update** I've tried. The probelm is that the open source driver is really slow.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, head to compiz-config -> workarounds and select the option that says "***keep a copy of the minimized windows***."

I experienced the same problem as you and this was solved.

I hope it works for you.

Greetings.

Answer (score -1):

meybe you applied some changes to settings in compiz manager wich causes problems  try to reset unity

- `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
- `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

  then
- `setsid unity`

  and restart Compiz:
- `setsid compiz --replace`

also you can try to restart X  Display Manager with`:

- `sudo -s setsid service lightdm restart`

instructions taken from ubuntuhelpguy :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwFG9XpdYEg  how to reset unity

Comment: Sorry but this is just reckless, there's no need to destroy his entire environment to do this.

Comment: thanks for your remark but it doesnt destroy anything att all,to destroy enviroment you have to remove unity package & ubuntu-desktop but here its just reseting 'compiz settings' to default wich you can manualy reapply again and restarting unity to default like in 12.04 lts release with- unity reset -command and nothing else

Comment: I will take your answer as a "last resource". Let's if someone has another idea...thanks!

Comment: thank for your kind reply ...as i did it by myself when i messed system up changing  to much settings in compiz manager and it worked perfectly. Actually its 'ubuntuhelpguy' advice as he has partnership with youtube and make tutorials on ubuntu( i posted the link if you hesitate). But hey thank you next time i would think before posting comment to someone needs help..